# Finding origin of coordinate system in svg chart

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

I try to find the coordinate system of my svg chart.
I made a circle which looks like this.
I made the circle out of Ring Arcs. So one Group is for example from A to F to E to A again.
I want to position a small circle within the circle.

However when I give the circle the coordinates 0, 0 it is where Point L is in the image.
I have no clue why the origin of the blip or small circle is on point L.

More importantly How can I let the circle behave like its in the big circle. That Math is working again.

Hopefully anyone can help.

Kind regards.
[image]

Comment: add the SVG as code into question so we can see what exactly you dealing with. It might be a transform matrix from parent object,... or whatever ... if you used [SVG elliptic arces they are pretty nasty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59300224/2521214)

Comment: it was a path element which automatically had preset coordinates. I replaced it with a circle element.