# Finding the Angle of a Point on Ellipse to use in GDI+

Tags: math, 2d, gdi+, direct2d

I am trying to create a system to convert arc parameters between 2D rendering formats (namely, Direct2D to GDI+). In Direct2D, arcs are defined by a start point, an end point, radii, rotation angle, sweep direction, and arc sweep size (above or below 180). In GDI+, they are defined by the bounding box, start angle, and ending angle (around the horizontal axis).

I need to convert from the Direct2D format into the GDI+ format. So far, I've been able to generate the bounding box but the angles are off. Below are images of what I should be getting (the Direct2D version) and what I am getting (in GDI+).

Expected:

[image: img]

Actual:

[image: img]

The code:

```
RectangleF bounds = GetBoundingBoxOfEllipse(startPoint, EndPoint, ArcRadii, RotationAngle);

PointF ctr = new PointF(bounds.Left + (bounds.Width / 2.0f), bounds.Top + (bounds.Height / 2.0f));

//I originally had +90 per the formula, but it was still wrong (too far the other way instead)
double ang1 = Math.Atan2(ctr.X - startPoint.X, ctr.Y - startPoint.Y) * (180.0 / Math.PI);
if (ang1 < 0)
    ang1 += 360.0;
double ang2 = Math.Atan2(ctr.X - EndPoint.X, ctr.Y - EndPoint.Y) * (180.0 / Math.PI);
if (ang2 < 0)
    ang2 += 360.0;

//Accounting for user options
double diffAng = Math.Abs(diffHeading(ang1, ang2));
if (ArcSize == ID2D1PathGeometry.Figure.ArcSegment.ArcSizeEnum.ArcSize_Large && diffAng < 180.0f)
    diffAng += 180.0;

if (SweepDirection == ID2D1PathGeometry.Figure.ArcSegment.SweepDirectionEnum.SweepDirection_Clockwise)
    diffAng *= -1.0;

path.AddArc(new RectangleF(bounds.X, bounds.Y, bounds.Width, bounds.Height), (float)ang1, (float)diffAng);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am pulling my hair out arbitrarily rotating these shapes. Thanks in advance!

**Edit**
For ease, I've also included the function for getting the ellipse bounding box.

```
RectangleF GetBoundingBoxOfEllipse(PointF startPoint, PointF endPoint, SizeF radii, float rotAngle)
{

    PointF v = new PointF((startPoint.X - endPoint.X) / 2.0f, (startPoint.Y - endPoint.Y) / 2.0f);
    //rotate if needed later
    double x1p = v.X;
    double y1p = v.Y;

    double rx = Math.Abs(radii.Width);
    double ry = Math.Abs(radii.Height);

    double lam = (Math.Pow(x1p, 2.0) / Math.Pow(rx, 2.0)) + (Math.Pow(y1p, 2.0) / Math.Pow(ry, 2.0));
    if(lam > 1)
    {
        rx = Math.Sqrt(lam) * rx;
        ry = Math.Sqrt(lam) * ry;
    }

    double sign = 1; //const sign = fa === fs ? -1 : 1;

    double div = (rx * rx * ry * ry - rx * rx * y1p * y1p - ry * ry * x1p * x1p) /
                 (rx * rx * y1p * y1p + ry * ry * x1p * x1p);

    double co = sign * Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs(div));

    v = new PointF((float)(((rx * y1p) / ry) * co), (float)(((-ry * x1p) / rx) * co));           
    v.X += (startPoint.X + endPoint.X) / 2.0f;
    v.Y += (startPoint.Y + endPoint.Y) / 2.0f;

    return new RectangleF(v.X - (radii.Width), v.Y - (radii.Height), radii.Width * 2.0f, radii.Height * 2.0f);
}
```

Comment: [Perhaps useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017100/calculate-center-of-svg-arc/12329083#12329083)

Comment: sounds like SVG arc... see: these: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41544540/2521214 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/59300224/2521214