# Is ARC clockwise or counterclockwise In SVG?

Tags: c#, math, svg, geometry

I have to draw an arc between two points at the edge of a circle. Assuming that the arc is drawn always in the shortest distance possible(edit2: sweep flag set to 0), I need to know if the arc is drawn clockwise or anticlockwise.

I got the following inputs:

1. start point (point1)
2. end point (point2)
3. center point
4. radius

[image]

Edit1: This question is related to arcs in svg. Hence its belongs to programming.

Comment: how on earth is this related to programming at all? Which geometry-lib are you talking about? Where is your code?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming, but purely about mathematics/geometry (that being said: draw a line through center and point 1 and look on which side of the line point 2 is)

Comment: SVG does not define CW/CCW of elliptic arc instead its defined as combination of larc/sweep flags along with the endpoints of your elliptic arc so the answer is arces might be both CW and CCW depends on occasion for more info see: [Converting an svg arc to lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41544540/2521214) .. so once you obtain the real center of arc you can use cross product to determine the CW/CCW ness of your arc

Comment: @FranzGleichmann its about svg fileformat ...

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain its specific to SVG fileformat representation of elliptic arcs ... code nor lib is not important for this...

Comment: but this site is about **programming**-issues, not about file-formats

Comment: Find sign of cross product of vectors `point1-center` and  `point2-center` to reveal shortest arc orientation

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain the question is coming up when drawing arcs in svg. Hence its a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing with a mathematician, I found an answer to this and based on that I wrote the following code:

```
public static bool IsClockWise(Point point1, Point point2, Circle circle)
        {
            var dxPoint1 = point1.X - circle.CenterX;
            var dyPoint1 = point1.Y - circle.CenterY;
            var dxPoint2 = point2.X - circle.CenterX;
            var dyPoint2 = point2.Y - circle.CenterY;


            double thetaPoint1 = 0, thetaPoint2 = 0;
            if (dxPoint1 > 0 && dyPoint1 >= 0)
                thetaPoint1 = Math.Asin(dyPoint1 / circle.Radius);
            else if (dxPoint1 <= 0 && dyPoint1 > 0)
                thetaPoint1 = Math.PI - Math.Asin(dyPoint1 / circle.Radius);
            else if (dxPoint1 < 0 && dyPoint1 <= 0)
                thetaPoint1 = Math.Abs(Math.Asin(dyPoint1 / circle.Radius)) + Math.PI;
            else if (dxPoint1 >= 0 && dyPoint1 < 0)
                thetaPoint1 = 2 * Math.PI - Math.Abs(Math.Asin(dyPoint1 / circle.Radius));

            if (dxPoint2 > 0 && dyPoint2 >= 0)
                thetaPoint2 = Math.Asin(dyPoint2 / circle.Radius);
            else if (dxPoint2 <= 0 && dyPoint2 > 0)
                thetaPoint2 = Math.PI - Math.Asin(dyPoint2 / circle.Radius);
            else if (dxPoint2 < 0 && dyPoint2 <= 0)
                thetaPoint2 = Math.Abs(Math.Asin(dyPoint2 / circle.Radius)) + Math.PI;
            else if (dxPoint2 >= 0 && dyPoint2 < 0)
                thetaPoint2 = 2 * Math.PI - Math.Abs(Math.Asin(dyPoint2 / circle.Radius));

            if (thetaPoint1 > thetaPoint2)
            {
                return !(thetaPoint1 - thetaPoint2 <= Math.PI);
            }

            return thetaPoint2 - thetaPoint1 <= Math.PI;

        }
```

Comment: OMG... Have you tried simple expression from my answer?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is SVG supports both clockwise and anticlockwise arcs.  You switch between them by changing the "sweep" flag in an arc (A) command.

If you want to learn how SVG arcs work, the place to look is the [Paths arcs section of the SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#paths-PathDataEllipticalArcCommands).

Comment: sweep flag is always 0 in my problem

Comment: Play with arcs in: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/

Answer (score 1):

Having described data, you can find what arc is smaller - CCW or CW one.

Just check sign of cross product of vectors `point1-center` and `point2-center` to reveal shortest arc orientation:

```
cp = (p1.x-c.x)*(p2.y-c.y)-(p1.y-c.y)*(p2.x-c.x)
```

For `cp>0` you have to set `sweep` parameter to 0, otherwise to 1 *(perhaps vice versa)*, whilst `large-arc-flag` should be always 0.

Comment: not sure how this will tell if the arc is clockwise or anticlockwise, which is the question. Sweep flag is always 0

Comment: Your question was about **the shortest distance possible**. This approach shows what direction gives shorter arc.

Comment: please read the title and question carefully. Thanks :)

Comment: Question says that you have to draw an arc. Is it true?